Upload to my own Youtube channel without user login everytime
I followed the documentation and created a C# client to upload videos to my channel. I only upload once a week, and every time I execute this function, I have to log in and give consent to the application.
My questions: Is there a way to upload to my own channel without user intervention. Ideally I want to automate this process to happen without involving a human.
Is there a way to get tokens silently, such as by using client credentials?
public async Task Upload(string filePath, VidData vidData)
{
    Notify("Preparing to upload to youtube, getting token...");
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
    }

    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });

    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = vidData.Title;
    video.Snippet.Description = vidData.Description;
    video.Snippet.Tags = vidData.Tags;
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See 
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"

    Notify("Token recived, Uploading to youtube...");
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
    }

